# Corona sdk local variable not getting the set data inside scene

Tags: android, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am new in corona and i am trying to create a gps inside a tab scene. I created a local variable loc where it is where the string of location data will be placed

```
local loc = "Loading" -- as initial value

then a location handler put a new value to it

local function locationHandler( event )
...
    loc = "the gps location"
end

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- create a white background to fill screen
    local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    bg:setFillColor( 255 )  -- white

    local title = display.newRetinaText(loc, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 20 )
    -- this is where the loc is placed in the title

    title:setTextColor( 0 ) -- black
    title:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    title.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    title.y = 170
end
```

the problem is loc still contains "Loading" when run in the device it works in the simulator though. I have checked and gps works fine and text that should be put in loc variable is ready to go in the inside handler, checked using logcat.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Forgot but there is also this line for the location handler -- Activate location listener
Runtime:addEventListener( "location", locationHandler )

Comment: also tried to put static text inside the location handler loc = "some other text" and Loading is still the text that shows so im making a mistake in changing value of a variable probably

Comment: I have deducted that setting values inside the location handler is the problem since I tried putting change of value outside the handler and it works. But i need the value of the location, tried modules and still doesn't work should i use database?

Comment: clearly your locationHandler function is not working at all, or is stopping before the line you want. Care to post a log?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
local title = display.newRetinaText(loc, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 20 )
```

makes a copy of a **loc** variable and passes it to RetinaText. To change the title use

```
title.text = "new text"
```

Consider this example:

```
local test = "1"
local function change( test )
    test = "2"
end
print(test)
change(test)
print(test)
```

It prints:

```
1
1
```